Girlfriend kisses boxer boyfriend even though he's bleeding from the nose
One scene I remember is a woman kissing a boxer who just lost a fight, despite him bleeding (from the nose, I think). Another is them in bed. I can't remember anything else, except that I saw this in the mid-90s and it could have been from the 80s or later. The movie had quite an impact on me... I found it to be great romance, but I just can't remember the name, nor any of the faces, other than that the couple was Caucasian.
Which movie is this?

Downvote is curious... sketchy details?

Sketchy details..... boxer movie, that has a couple in it.

I wish I could remember more.

You could expound on when you saw it, what era the movie was from, etc. There are a lot of details which could help.

Reminded me of Never Back Down but it doesn't match time era. Can you elaborate a plot little more.

@AnkitSharma I wish I remembered more.

It's not what I would term great romance, but there is a caucasian lead in the movie "Gladiator" (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104346/) from 1992. IIRC, there are a couple affectionate scenes just after fights, one of which the actor is pretty beat up.

I think I've seen that, but should check it out again just to make sure. Thanks @JohnP.

After a revisit, I'd say that's the one @JohnP, though the bleeding guy did not get the kiss... Maybe I am misremembering that moment. I found the whole thing rather poor, but can imagine liking it a lot more in the 90s.

@Tshepang - I put it as an answer. And while it's not a world shaker movie, I quite enjoy it and watch it probably once a year or so.

I'm guessing you're not talking about any of the Rocky movies. I'm not sure you actually ever see them in bed, but the bleeding, kissing, (losing) and timeframe does match pretty accurate.
Else you reminded me of this : Play it to the bone. Though the time frame is a bit off.

Definitely not Rocky. I think I would have remembered Stallone's face. I should check the other, though I think would have remembered the Banderas face also.

And there are a couple of scenes in the Rocky series where they are in bed discussing things.

I believe you are talking about the movie "Gladiator", which is a mid 90's movie about underground or "smoker" boxing events. The protagonist is a Golden Gloves boxer forced to fight to pay off his dad's gambling debts. He is Caucasian, and his friend/fellow fighter is played by Cuba Gooding Jr., while Brian Dennehey, Robert Loggia and Jon Seda also played primary roles.
Quite a high powered cast for the level of the movie, actually.
